# переход в защищённый режим и обратно

Tags: ассемблер, виртуальная-машина, dos

переписал старый вопрос, добавил код. 
 Есть код который переводит dos в защищённый режим -

```
...
decr   struc
limit  dw    0
base_1 dw    0
base_m db    0
attr_1 db    0
attr_2 db    0
base_h db    0
desr   ends
data segment
;так же в полях сегмента данных указал и заполнил 4 дескриптора, первый из
```

которых нулевой, с типом сегментов для кода 98h, для стэка, данных 92h
    data ends
    ...
    text   segment
    ...
    mov    eax,cr0
    or     eax,1
    mov    cr0,eax
    ...
    text   ends
    ...

а затем обратно. c помощью сброса процессора
(этот код отрабатывает нормально) -

```
...
;подготовительная часть с сохранением адреса программы в которую надо 
вернуться после сброса процессора
mov    ax,40h
mov    es,ax
mov    word ptr ES:[67h],offset return
mov    ES:[69h],CS
mov    al,0Fh
out    70h,al
mov    al,0Ah
out    71h,al
...
...
;сам сброс процессора
mov    al,0FEh
out    64h,al
halt
...
```

А вот код перехода обратно в реальный режим посредством изменения бита в регистре CR0 и подготовке теневых регистров(то есть заменяем способ перехода, и не вводим в память BIOS адрес возврата) -

```
...
;подготовка полей дескрипторов сегментов к реальному режиму
mov    gdt_stk.limit,0ffffh
mov    gdt_code.limit,0ffffh
mov    gdt_data.limit,0ffffh
;подготовка сегментных регистров
push   ds
pop    ds
push   ss
pop    ss
;дальний переход для загрузки сегментного регистра CS
db     0EAh
dw     offset toRm
dw     16
;сброс первого бита CR0
toRm:
mov    eax,CR0
and    eax,0FFFFFFFEh
mov    CR0,eax    
db     0EAh       ;уже находимся в реальном режиме
dw     offset return
dw     text
;восстановление регистров для реального режима
return:
mov    ax,data
mov    ds,ax
mov    ax,stk
mov    ss,stk
...
```

Второй способ возврата никак не отрабатывает, виснет ms-dos.
ms-dos установлен на виртуалках(wmware, virtualbox, dosBox).
MS-dos на реальном железе с flash-hdd в обоих вариантах возврата перезагружает компьютер.
 При том выполнение работы в защищённом режиме происходит корректно, по TD показывает что при помещении обратно в регистр CR0 происходит зависание виртуалки.
 Я бы мог понять если бы он неправильно отрабатывал только на виртуальной машине, но на реальном железе... Подскажет кто, почему такое происходит?

Comment: здравствуйте. поправил, return метка следующая сразу же после dw text, text это text segment, то есть сегмент кода.

Comment: можно удалить вопрос, в книжке была ошибка.